# Disable tooltip for a function

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone have an idea how to hide the tooltip that appears during writing a function in Visual Studio Code? I don't really need a full description of every function every time I type it, this feature is a huge overkill. It's not about hovering - these tooltips pop up during typing. It's also not about the suggestions for variables/functions.

I use Visual Studio Code with following extensions: Python, Pylint, Pylance, Code Runner, autopep8.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPwtv.png)

I've look through the settings and searched the web for over an hour but I failed to find the answer.

Comment: there is a setting for that but you want these tooltips if you use the non-standard functions, just type as if it is not there, or press Esc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in visual studio code

1. Go to "File" -> "Preferences" -> "Settings" (or use the shortcut
   Ctrl+, on Windows/Linux or Cmd+, on macOS) to open the settings.
2. In the settings, search for "Parameter Hints" or navigate to "Text
   Editor" -> "Parameter Hints".
3. Uncheck the checkbox next to "Parameter Hints" to disable the
   feature.

   Close the settings. warning it will applied to all programming languages in vscode.